# The "if" condition is not working properly

Tags: java, oop

I don't know why my if else condition not working properly. it'll print "Try again" no matter what(input correct or wrong data).please help. thankyou so much in advance.

```
public class InventoryManagementSystem {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Administrator obj = new Administrator();
    String str = "123";
    
    System.out.print("Enter user ID: ");
    String userID = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print("Enter user password: ");
    int userPassword = Integer.parseInt(str);
    str = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.print("Enter user Phone Number: ");
    long phoneNo = Integer.parseInt(str);
    str = input.nextLine();
    
    Administrator obj1 = new Administrator(userID, userPassword);
    Administrator obj2 = new Administrator(userID, userPassword, phoneNo);
    
    User obj3 = new User();
    
    System.out.println("ID : ");
    String ID = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Password : ");
    int pass = Integer.parseInt(str);
    str = input.nextLine();
    
    User obj4 = new User(ID,pass);
      
    if (userPassword==pass && userID.equals(ID)){
        System.out.println("Login succesfully!");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Try Again");
    }
   
}
```

}

Comment: Wait one second... is the password meant to be numeric and the ID string? You'd better take a second look at your program, bearing that question in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following lines out of order throughout the code.

This :-

```
    System.out.println("Password : ");
    int pass = Integer.parseInt(str);
    str = input.nextLine();
```

should be this :-

```
    System.out.println("Password : ");
    str = input.nextLine();
    int pass = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always parsing userPassword with default value "123".

```
 Working Code:

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Administrator obj = new Administrator();
    String str = "123";

    System.out.print("Enter user ID: ");
    String userID = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter user password: ");
    str = input.nextLine();
    int userPassword = Integer.parseInt(str);


    System.out.print("Enter user Phone Number: ");
    str = input.nextLine();
    long phoneNo = Integer.parseInt(str);


    Administrator obj1 = new Administrator(userID, userPassword);
    Administrator obj2 = new Administrator(userID, userPassword, phoneNo);

    User obj3 = new User();

    System.out.println("ID : ");
    String ID = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Password : ");
    int pass = Integer.parseInt(str);
    str = input.nextLine();

    User obj4 = new User(ID, pass);

    if (userPassword == pass && userID.equals(ID)) {
        System.out.println("Login succesfully!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Try Again");
    }
```